# vsto - determine a word document if created from blank document or open from an existing document

Tags: vsto

any expert here got any idea how I can determine a word document if created from blank document or open from an existing document.

I am using Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Saved but it seems not enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do

```
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(WordInstance.ActiveDocument.Path))
   {
       throw new ApplicationException("Document must be saved first");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

for vsto developers, please go here

```
if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Path == String.Empty)
    {
        Word.Dialog dlg;
        Object timeout = 3000;
        dlg = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Dialogs[
            Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSaveAs];
        int result = dlg.Display(ref timeout);
    }
    else
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Save();
    }
```

The result will store which button is pressed (0- cancel, 1- ok, 2- close)

Comment: Is this for an old version? For Word 2010 at least, the returned numbers are not correct, it's -1 for OK (really should be an enumeration), and 0 is returned for any type of cancellation. All the save dialog info is extraneous to the question anyway.